# Joining single record in one MYSQL table to two records in a second

Tags: mysql

I have two MYSQL tables, teams and fixtures. They look like this...

```
TEAMS
   team_id   |   team   
---------------------------------
      1      | Manchester United  
      2      | Liverpool  
      3      | Chelsea

FIXTURES
fixture_id  |    date    |  home_team_id   |   away_team_id   
--------------------------------------------------------------
    1       | 2014-01-06 |       1         |        2 
    2       | 2014-02-06 |       2         |        3  
    3       | 2014-03-06 |       3         |        1
```

What I am trying to do is write a query that produces a result like...

```
   fixture_id  |   date     |  home_team         |   away_team   
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
       1       | 2014-01-06 |  Manchester United |   Liverpool 
       2       | 2014-02-06 |  Liverpool         |   Chelsea 
       3       | 2014-03-06 |  Chelsea           |   Manchester United
```

How do I join both the home_team_id and away_team_id in a single fixtures table to two team_id records in the teams table?

Thanks for your help

Jules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to join to the TEAMS table twice, like so:

```
select fixture_id, date, h.team as home_team, a.team as away_team
from fixtures f
inner join teams h on f.home_team_id = h.team_id
inner join teams a on f.away_team_id = a.team_id
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks. I had tried something similar to this but had added an AND between the two join statements which returned results. Thank you to everybody for the various solutions.

Comment: `AND` is to perform a Boolean operation on the conditions. For joins, you just append the next join statement.

Answer (score 0):

You need to JOIN TEAMS two times something as

```
select 
f.fixture_id,
f.date,
t1.team as home_team,
t2.team as away_team
from FIXTURES f
join TEAMS t1 on t1.team_id = f.home_team_id
join TEAMS t2 on t2.team_id = f.away_team_id
```

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem. Join the team table to times to the FIXTURES table

```
select fixture_id,date,hometeam.team,awayteam.team from    FIXTURES join TEAMS hometeam on home_team_id = hometeam.id join TEAMS awayteam on home_team_id = awayteam.id
```